# Is there an efficient and standardised code for multiple OpenGL ES Views on Iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

First of all thanks for taking the time to read through and attempt to help with the problem I'm having. First question posted here and after reading through the startup agreement I'll try and be descriptive as possible =)

I'm currently working on a Game for the Iphone as my final year university project. This game is one I hope to continue working on and expanding after I leave and use as a springboard for my CV into the industry. I've got a good few months left, so plenty of time to take things slowly and carefully plan it out.

I have a background in Java and OpenGL in C++ so I understand some of the basic fundamentals. I'm not that experienced in Objective C yet, need to start somewhere =), so I apologise for any obvious mistakes I'm making. The current state of code is i've got multiple items rendering to a single OpenGL ES view based on the OpenGL ES 1.1 model. I feel since the project is primarily 2D I shouldn't need to go to the higher version.  I would post up the code I have but it's full of prototyping and misc code and is incredibly messy. In fact I wouldn't mind restarting the code as a multi view template then moving over the blocks of code as I get them working.

I've done research through many different mediums as to the ideal way to create a multi view application with each view being OpenGL-ES based. I've seen many tutorials on using the UI-kit view with an OpenGL view, but I've decided the best way for my project to ensure full dynamic and customisation I'd be happier using openGL for all the views.

TL;DR:
The question I'm trying to ask is if theres a good tutorial or template anywhere I'm missing that will allow me to start up a new multi view project that will allow me to switch between multiple views (Menus etc)?

Comment: do yourself a favor, throw away your prototype code

Comment: The prototype code will be thrown away, hense it being a prototype. But until I can get a multiple view code working I don't have anything else to work with.

Comment: I guess what you'd probably want is multiple view controllers, each with a separate EAGLView? Do you want to share a rendering context between the lot of them?

Comment: What do you mean by switching to multiple views?  You wish to only have one OpenGL scene being displayed at once, but the ability to switch scenes, or do you want to have more than one side-by-side OpenGL display?

Answer (score 0):

You can't go far wrong with [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) if you're making a 2D app but want it to be openGL accelerated.

Comment: cocos2d is not compatible with OpenGLES2.0